# Magento preventing two product types in same cart

Tags: php, magento

I have a custom attrib... call it.. IsRestricted that each product has assigned to it.  It has a 1 or 0.  I want to check the existing cart to see if it has a restricted item.  If it does and I am attempting to add a non-restricted item to it, I need to post a message saying only restricted OR non-restricted items can be in the cart at the same time.
So if the items in the cart all have a 0 then you can only add new items with a 0 if the items in the cart have a 1 then you can only add items with a 1.

I am on the community version..Magento ver. 1.9.2.1
Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance..

-Ken

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `public function addAction()` in `./app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php` and iterate through all items in cart:

```
$_items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach ($_items as $_item) {
    // ...
    // $_item->getProduct()->getData('IsRestricted');
    // ...
}
```